# my flutter project got an error in red screen

Tags: flutter

i am wiring a online store app , in authentication state of the users step , i got a red screen error , anyone can help me with this ?

error is : `NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.auth'`

i tried to re run the app but not fixed , and checked my resources code but all were the same

```
    class root extends StatelessWidget {
  root({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final Future<FirebaseApp> firebaseTest = Firebase.initializeApp();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: firebaseTest,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text(
                'Firebase is not connected',
                style: Consts.textStyleOne,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
            builder: (context, streamSnapshot) {
              if (streamSnapshot.hasError) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      '${streamSnapshot.error}',
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
              if (streamSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              
                User? user = streamSnapshot.data as User?;
                if (user == null) {
                  return LoginPage();
                } else {
                  return Home();
                }
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem!
At first as I wanted run my app on web , because it use less than emulator hardware resources.
my error just occurred when I started my app on the web. I tried to plug my phone to the pc then I re run my app on my mobile and no red screen appeared any more.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).